# Link to external URL in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a link to external website but am encountering an "Undefined method" runtime error with the code I've produced. What am I doing wrong?

show.html.erb:

`<%= redirect_to "http://www.google.com", :class => "website_1" do %>`

```
  <span class="s1">
    <span class="s2"><%= user.website %></span>
  </span>
```

<% end %>

Error:
`` undefined method `redirect_to' for #<#:0x00000102af1808> ``

I've tried link_to but I thought link_to is inherited from url_to which the purpose is to utilize routes?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly does the error message say? What method is undefined for what object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`redirect_to` is not designed to create links, you should dive into `link_to`.

[Doc here.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Comment: I've tried link_to but I thought link_to is inherited from url_to which the purpose is to utilize routes?

Comment: It can do both. Look at the last example of `link_to` in the doc, it uses a custom link

Answer (score 1):

You should use `link_to` not `redirect_to`!